# Using FORFILES in a FOR loop and trying to override the error

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm writing a for loop to execute the forfiles command on both .xml and .psr files. Currently, if it finds one file type but not the other, it will display "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria", but I want the error to say which file type wasn't found. I have an if statement inside the for loop that's supposed to override the error, but it's not working. Here's the loop:

```
FOR %%G IN (.xml, .psr) DO (
    FORFILES /P "%xmlDir%" /M *%%G /D -%days% /C "CMD /C DEL @FILE"
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        ECHO No matches found for %%G files older than %days% days
    )
)
```

Edit: Thanks for the answers. My for loop now works as intended and ended up looking like this:

```
FOR %%G IN (.xml, .psr) DO (
    FORFILES /P "%xmlDir%" /M *%%G /D -%days% /C "CMD /C DEL @FILE" >nul 2>nul
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        ECHO No %%G files %days% days old or older were found.
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %%G files as old as %days% days or older have been deleted.
    )
)
```

Comment: you have a [delayed expansion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028). Do don't, when you use `if not errorlevel 0 (`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard `delayed expansion` error - You need to invoke delayedexpansion [hundreds of SO articles about that - use the search feature] in order to display or use the run-time value of any variable that's changed within a parenthesised series of instructions (aka "code block").

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
```

is the problem - `errorlevel` is replaced by its value when the `for` is encountered.

The easy way around this is to use conventional `errorlevel` processing:

```
if errorlevel 1 (
```

ie. if `errorlevel` is (1 or greater than 1)

As for the message, try `2>nul` to redirect errormessages to `nul` OR use

```
if exist "%xmldir%\%%G" (forfiles...
 ) else (echo no %%G files found)
```